# Как лучше организовать код сложной статусной модели в БД?

Tags: база-данных, модель-данных

Есть БД в которой есть достаточно много объектов - для упрощения считаем что это документы. Каждой такой документ представлен несколькими связанными таблицами в БД. У каждого документа есть статусная модель - т.е. каждый документ за свой жизненный цикл проходит через определенные статусы, которые в БД представлены полем в соответствующей таблице БД документа. Некий конечный автомат по каждому документу. Переходы между статусами проходят в зависимости от ряда условий - например, поступила оплата от клиента или нет, истекла определенная дата или нет. Часть статусов меняется джобами БД которые каждый день запускаются и проверяют условия перехода статусов. 
Проблема в том что статусные модели документов взаимозависимы. Т.е. статус документа зависит от статусов других документов. Т.е. на самом деле все статусные модели документов вместе представляют единую систему. И так как система стало достаточно большой то увидеть картину целиком - что от чего зависит и при каких условиях переходит стало очень сложно - код смены статусов каждого документа раскидан по разным пакетам. Хотелось бы как то найти решение чтобы можно было глянуть на систему целиком - не противоречива ли система статусов, нет ли "тупиков" и т.д. Какие решения здесь могут помочь?   Стоит ли как-то отрефакторить код, есть ли какие-то пригодные для данной ситуации решения облегчающие жизнь?

Comment: Для каждой пары документов в части статусов имеется некая зависимость: "зависит от", "влияет на" или тупо "не влияет". Последний вариант игнорируем, а остаток образует обычный ориентированный граф. Стройте и анализируйте на предмет связности и цикличности.

Comment: А таблица со статусами одна или они то же раскиданы по нескольким таблицам ? Если по нескольким - то для начала свести их в одну таблицу, что бы было унифицированное понятие "документ". потом определить виды событий по которым происходит изменение статусов. сейчас явно видны 2: истечение времени и обновление информации в бд (поступление оплаты например). А после да, рефакторить код так, что бы единый механизм по событиям вызывал обработчики и если они вернули "ok" менял статус по некой таблице изменения состояний. в общем рефакторинг, боюсь, очень серьезный понадобится

Comment: Разные таблицы статусов для разных документов. Условия смены статусов включают кроме статусов других документов еще несколько показателей. Думал создать единую таблицу состояний - но как лучше код организовать тогда? таблица будет аховая по количеству колонок и строк. И всю логику этой таблицы переходов в один пакет? Или еще какие-то возможности есть?

Answer (score 0):

Приходится отвечать на собственный вопрос, потому что необходимость заставила разобраться.

Вышеописанная система статусов нарушает основные принципы построения реляционных баз данных. Нарушаются принципы нормализации таблиц - "в одном месте только один факт" и "один факт только в одном месте". Что такое статус в описанной системе? Это некоторая интегральная характеристика которая отражает что происходило с документом (Подготовлен, Подписан, Отправлен, Удален...), и даже что происходило с другими связанными документами. Поэтому фактически в одном месте мы храним информацию о других полях (дата отправки, дата подписания, флаг логического удаления и т.д.).

Решение только одно правильное - нормализовать таблицы,не путать теплое с мягким. А статусы сделать вычисляемыми, а не полями в таблицах.